# Integrating Python and C++ MacOS PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT Undeclared

Tags: python, c++, xcode, macos

I am facing this issue while developing on XCode. Unable to find anything online. I don't even have any idea if this issue is related to XCode or it's a general issue.

So Here is my sample code:

```
#include "myModule.h"
#include <Python/Python.h>
int Cfib(int n){
    if (n<2){
        return n;
    }
    else{
        return Cfib(n-1)+Cfib(n-2);
    }
}

static PyObject* fib(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    int n;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &n)){
        return NULL;
    }
    return Py_BuildValue("i", Cfib(n));
}

static PyObject* version(PyObject* self){
    return Py_BuildValue("s", "Version 1.0");
}

static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {

    {"fib", fib, METH_VARARGS, "Calculate the fibonacci numbers."},
    {"version", (PyCFunction)version, METH_NOARGS, "Tells us the version of our module."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}

};

static struct PyModuleDef myModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,  // Use of undeclared indentifier PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT
    "myModule",
    "Fibnoacci Module",
    -1,
    myMethods
};
```

Does anyone have any idea what to do to have ** PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT**? What is the default Method Head Definition value which I can declare to overcome?

Or should I just turn towards Linux environment for further development?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used `PyModule_HEAD_INIT` in your `myModule` definition, but that's not an identifier declared by CPython. You're probably thinking of `PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT` (note the `Def`).

As for whether you should develop under Linux instead: So far, the problems you've experienced have not been the fault of your tools. It seems unlikely that switching over would help in that respect.

Comment: I am editing the PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT. Mistake because of typing instead of copying. "_"

Comment: It remains the same. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: It's also possible that you're including the Python 2.x header while using the Python 3.x format for module definition.

Comment: Let me look into it.

Comment: Thanks issue solved. I changed the XCODE to work with Python3 :) thanks again